# UWP. Как создать модульное приложение?

Tags: c#, архитектура, плагин, windowsphone, uwp

Как создать модульное приложение? Чтобы можно было бы подгружать новые модули, предоставляющие дополнительный функционал. Т.е. запустив приложение, можно увидеть установленные модули и доступные новые для загрузки и установки. Как и где хранить модули, и как реализовать связь с основным модулем?

Comment: Ничего не понятно, можете конкретизировать вопрос примером?

Comment: Классическая реализации модульной архитектуры опирается на загрузку сторонних сборок. Windows Phone же позволяет загружать в память только сборки, подписанные Microsoft. Сборки, которые вы скачаете "из интернета", таковыми не являются.

Comment: Слишком они нахренавертили с WinPhone. Слишком закрытая система в отличии от того же Android. Очень! много ограничений. Я в свое время просто забил на нее. Если хотите делать что-то серьезное - выберите другую мобильную ОС.

Comment: Я бы еще посмотрел в сторону динамической компиляции если там не сильно тяжелый код - попробуйте System.CodeDom.Compiler. Т.е. хранить код плагинов в текстовиках, и динамически компилировать и запускать.

Comment: @z668 компиляция тоже недоступна.

Comment: @andreycha, вообще в System.CodeDom.Compiler написано что WP 8.1 поддерживает.

Comment: @z668 из этого неймспейса там есть только `GeneratedCodeAttribute`.

Comment: Значит неверная документация, вот о чем я: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.codedom.compiler.codecompiler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: получается, что задача не выполнима. жаль. попробую покопать в сторону динамических ресурсов.

Comment: на первый взгляд, похоже на [ссылка](http://habrahabr.ru/company/2gis/blog/259335/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

реализовал используя Caliburn.Micro. навело на мысли -  [ссылка](http://habrahabr.ru/company/2gis/blog/259335/).

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите [Managed Extensibility Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Также советую книгу CLR via C# - в одной из глав рассказывается про создание приложения с плагинами.